# Rearrange array with sum and length n while minimizing distance change

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, minimization

An array A[n] (length *n*) of nonnegative integers is given. The array contains *n* objects dispersed through itself, so that A[i] represents the number of objects in slot i, and the sum from i=0 to n of A[i] is *n*. We must rearrange the array such that each element is 1. We are given that *n* <= 10^5. (So O(n^2) is too slow, but O(n log n) is fine.)

Rearranging works as follows: if A[i] = k and A[j] = h, then we can decrease A[i] by some positive integer m <= k and increase some element A[j] by m correspondingly, so that A[i] = k-m and A[j] = h+m. However, each rearrange has a cost given by Cost(m, i, j) = m d(i, j)^2 (proportional to the square of the distance of the rearrange). The array works such that the distance function d(i, j) is standard subtraction, but it can wrap around the array, so if n = 7 then d(1, 4)=3, but d(0, 6) = 1 and d(1,5) = 3, etc. That is, we can think of the array as "circular."

The total cost is given by the sum of the cost function over all rearranges, and our goal is to find the minimum value of the cost function such that A[i] = 1 for all i, i.e. all the elements are equal to 1. Each object can only be rearranged once, so for example if A = [5,0,0,0,0] we can't just move an object from A[0] to A[1] and then to A[2] to circumvent the squaring of the distance.

Help on an algorithm or pseudocode/code to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting problem! Is the O(n^2) vs O(n log n) point about the size of the cost function or the computation time? I'm guessing that we basically have a limit of O(n log n) computation and just want to minimize the cost function within this bound but can you please clarify? Also, it sounds squaring the distance is artificial, because e.g. if A = [5, 0, 0, 0, 0] you could get to [4, 0, 1, 0, 0] you could just do 2 rearrangements for a cost of 2 * 1^2 = 2 instead of doing a single rearrangement for a cost of 1 * 2^2 = 4. So effectively, you can move things around for Cost(m,i,j) = m*d(i,j)?

Comment: Oops, sorry that the squaring distance wasn't clear -- I meant to say that each number can only be moved once, if that makes sense. That is, you can think of it like there are 5 objects in A[0], and each object can only be moved once. Also, O(n log n) is a computation time limit (because 10^10 computations takes too long).

Comment: Hmmm, it sounds like each index can only be the destination of a rearrangement once. E.g. in the [5, 0, 0, 0, 0] example you'd have to do four operations that all come from that leading 5, but all those zeros can only be turned into a 1, can't put more than 1 in them and then move the excess later. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, each index would only be a destination once. In your example the answer would be 4 + 1 + 4 + 1 = 10 (those are the costs to move an object to the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th slot respectively).

Comment: Very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531225/algorithm-for-solving-this-distributing-beads-puzzle)